# Convert 3D-dataframe to 2D-dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-conversion

I have a three dimensional excel table which I would like to convert into a two dimensional dataframe that I can use in R. I think the best way is to read it in R and then transform it directly within R, but I do not find how. Here is an example. I have a df1-like dataframe that I want to transform to df2:

```
a1 <- paste("a","b","c",sep = ";")
a2 <- paste("e","f","g",sep = ";")

df1 <- data.frame(v1=a1, v2=a2, row.names = "w1")
df2 <- data.frame(w1=c(rep("v1",3),rep("v2",3)), "value"=letters[1:6])
```

Comment: I have multiple rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using reshape2

```
sub_df1 <- apply(df1,2,FUN= strsplit,split = ";")
# $v1
# $v1$w1
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
# $v2 
# $v2$w1
# [1] "e" "f" "g
sub_df2 <- sapply(apply(df1,2,FUN= strsplit,split = ";"), FUN = unlist,use.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)
#     v1  v2 
# w11 "a" "e"
# w12 "b" "f"
# w13 "c" "g"
melt(sub_df2)[-1]
#    Var2 value
# 1   v1     a
# 2   v1     b
# 3   v1     c
# 4   v2     e
# 5   v2     f
# 6   v2     g
```

You can then delete the first column by adding the `[-1]`

Comment: Thank you very much, it is exactly what I was looking for. I thought about the melt function, but I was lacking the splitting step.

Comment: You could potentially use melt directly instead of `sub_df2`. However, I'm unsure how to get the column name..